# How to pass a lambda as an extra of an Intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I'm new to kotlin and Android, and i was looking into recyclerView but ran into a few hiccups.
Basically i have,
+ 2 Activities, MainActivity containig a recyclerView and fullDetails activity that opens with onClick on each ticket of the recyclerView,
[Activity A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exwml.png) & [Activity B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltJTX.png)
The Fab show show a function unique to each item, like a Toast as in this example.
+An ArrayList of objects,**tempMenuList** of **options** class,
+The class contains a few strings an a lambda variable **actionOfItem** as i want to have individual functions for each object,
+I'm trying to pass the lambda through an intent as serializable throught the OnClick Listener like this:

```
val intent=Intent(context,fullDetails::class.java)
intent.putExtra("action",Runnable{tempMenuList[position].actionOfItem} as java.io.Serializable)
```

+On Activity B, I get the lambda like this and try to call the function, as this was crashing my app, I made a seperate **actions** class for the lambda's so that i can write getSerializable() as an object of *actions* class.

```
val action=bundle.getSerializable("function") as actions?
fabShow.setOnClickListener{
          action?.action
    }
```

Now the app loads the MainActivity,but Crashes when The OnClickListner of the RecyclerView is pressed.
I know my naming is super bad and confusing and i don't use comments,
but is there any way to pass a unique function for each object through an intent?
Edit 1: I read that i can do this using SharedPreferences, but it isn't reccommended.
Here's the Logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.androidreferenceapp.MainActivity$menuAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1$1 cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
    at com.example.androidreferenceapp.MainActivity$menuAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:58)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6605)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6582)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

[Here's the full Source Code if that helps](https://github.com/Sharkaboi/androidReferenceApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidreferenceapp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runnables aren't Serializable. You can't simply cast whatever to Serializable to make it serializeable--it's an interface you have to implement. And you can't serialize object references, so it would be impossible to do this with a function.

Your data (`tempMenuList` in this case) should be in a ViewModel. The Activities should be converted into Fragments that are both housed in the same Activity. The first Fragment can simply pass the Int index of the item in the list via the Intent, and the second Fragment can retrieve the item and its `action` from the ViewModel.

Comment: ViewModels are super new to me, but i'll start looking into them.   
From what i understand till now, Instead of all these classes, I can just create a myViewModel class which holds my list, create an object in MainActivity and Activity B, add elements to my list in main activity and pass the index, but how will the object of the view model in Activity B have the same data as the object in MainActivity?
Sorry for being dumb, I can't understand much i read about view models and liveData.

Comment: It's a design pattern called MVVM. An Activity is a UI, and shouldn't be in charge of managing data, only displaying it and passing along user input. A ViewModel is a class you write to contain and manage your data. An Activity or Fragment can get an instance of a ViewModel using `val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels`. Google recommends against multiple Activities because it is so hard to pass data between them(https://youtu.be/2k8x8V77CrU?t=343), but with Fragments you can share a single ViewModel whose instance has the same lifetime as the Activity and will survive device rotations.

Comment: You don't have to use LiveData in your ViewModel, but it makes it easier to make the Fragments less coupled to managing data. A LiveData is just a wrapper for any kind of object, such as your `tempMenuList`. By wrapping it in a LiveData, you allow the Fragment to simply get a callback whenever the data changes instead of having to actively check when new data is available. So then your Fragment doesn't have to be aware of any of the reasons the data might change. It just registers one observer that passes along the new data to your RecyclerView's adapter.

Comment: Before ViewModel, Android didn't have an official way to handle the MVVM pattern. And new programmers that didn't know better would put all of their code directly into an Activity, turning it into a god-class that has to be aware of everything that happens to data and making sure all the views are kept up-to-date, etc. It sure didn't help that the official developer guides showed everything happening in Activities. People who did know better used third-party tools like ReactiveX to make something akin to ViewModels and LiveData.

Answer (score 1):

Easy with `Parcelable`.

**1. Add `id 'kotlin-parcelize'` in your build.gradle file.**

**2. Wrap your Lambda inside a Class:**

```
@Parcelize
class Listener(val clickAction: () -> Unit) : Parcelable {
    fun onClick() = clickAction()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is an anti-pattern. You should instead pass the lambda as an argument to the recyclerview's adapter if possible. 
for example

```
//adapter class
class MyAdapter(
private val items: List<MyModel>,
private val clickListener: (item: MyModel) -> Unit
) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyModelViewHolder>() {
   //adapter boilerplate
....
//viewholder class
inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
 fun bind(item: MyModel){
   itemView.setOnClickListener{
      clickListener(item)
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can handle click events on the Activity which created the RecyclerView.

```
val myList = listOf(item1, item2...)
val adapter = MyAdapter(myList,  {item->
 //do whatever you want with item
})
```

This gives you more flexibility and is fairly easier to implement as well.

Note that, serialization is a very expensive thing to do in android, which was why Parcelables were made. But in your use case, you can avoid both.

Comment: Hey, Sorry if my wording was wrong, but The lambda I was passing was for an OnClickListener for a Button in Activity B not the RecyclerView item's OnClickListener. I did clean up my code from your suggestion though, so Thanks!